# Extracting Residuals values and Date from lm, when lapply is used

Tags: r, list, linear-regression, lapply, lm

I have a dataframe with 507 columns. Column 1 is the date of observation. Columns 2 through 504 are my dependent variables. The 505, 506, and 507 columns are the independent variables. I have written a functinon to do a separate regression for each of the dependent variables:

```
varlist<-names(df)[2:504]

models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  lm( na.action = na.exclude,
    substitute(i ~ rmrf + smb + hml, 

               list(i = as.name(x))
    ), 
    data = df)
})
```

How do I export all the residual results into a separate dataframe, along with corresponding headings for which dependent variable it came from and what date it came from?

I can access residuals from a single model using this method:

```
resid(models[[1]])
```

But I am unable to identify which dependent variable this applies to and what date (observation) the residual corresponds to. Also, I haven't found a method to export residuals from all 503 models.

`Resid(models[[1:503]])` gives me the following error:

Error in models[[1:503]] : recursive indexing failed at level 3

Comment: 1. You can use `list2env()` to convert a named list to an environment. 2. Your list `models` has 503 elements, and each corresponds sequentially to `names(df)[2:504]`. 3. You can extract your residuals from each model with something like `lapply(models, resid)`

Comment: lapply(models, resid)->(residuals_df) correctly applied the resid function to all elements of models. I did as.data.frame(residuals_df) to get all residuals in one table. However, I still need the date column as an index and each column name labelled with the dependent variable names instead of numeric values for where they appear in the models list.

Comment: list2env(models) gives the following error: Error in list2env(models) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x

Comment: Your models list is unnamed so list2env() is failing. The solutions I gave are just hackish ways of continuing your code. The way you are structuring and storing your model is far from optimal. If you want, I'll respond a full solution from scratch as the answer.

Comment: That'd be great! Or just point me in the right direction. I'm fairly new to R programming, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# All the dep var
x = df[,505:507]

# All the indep var
y = df[,2:504]

# Fit all the models, use a little bit of scoping abuse
list_models  = lapply(y, function(y) with(x, lm(y~rmf + smb + htl)))

# Get resid for all models
list_resid = lapply(list_models, resid) 

# If you want them in a data.frame instead of list
df_resid = do.call(cbind.data.frame, list_resid)

# Add the dates
df_resid = cbind(date = df[,1], df_resid)

# Reproducible example, just generating some fake data in the same structure as your data
df = matrix(runif(50*507), nrow = 50, ncol = 507)
df = data.frame(df)
df[,1] = seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), as.Date("2017/2/19"), "days")
names(df) = paste0("var", 1:507)
names(df)[505:507] = c("rmf", "smb", "htl")
names(df)[1] = "Date"
```

Comment: This works great! I still need to extract the date for each of the residuals. It looks like if I use na.action = exclude then it retains the NA values, so all the dates across the residuals should be consistent. How would I retain the date in the residual dataframe?

Comment: @user6883405 See edit in answer. Forgot about the dates. Just add them to your data.frame, no 'extraction' needed.

Comment: Thanks for your update. However, the dates are "trading days" for stocks, so they exclude weekends and certain holidays. Therefore I can't just add a sequential date column as you've suggested.

Comment: I'd also like to retain the independent variable values for each residual value; what inputs of "rmrf",  "smb", and "hml" yield that specific residual.

Comment: I solved the issue by using rbind to bind the residuals to the original df: cbind(df, df_resid)